# Setting status of HTTP request

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to set the http status in my custom API when a request is being made.

```
protected $statusCode = 200;

public function setStatusCode($statusCode) {
        $this->statusCode = $statusCode;
        return $this;
    }

public function respond($data, $headers = []) {
        return response()->json($data, $this->getStatusCode(), $headers);
    }

public function respondCreated($message) {
    return $this->setStatusCode(201)->respond([
        'message' => $message
    ]);
}

$this->respondCreated("Incident was created");
```

But when I make my server request in POSTMAN, I see status 200 and not 201 as set in the code above and the message is not appearing at all. Do I need to do it differently?

I am using the Laravel framework and implemented the functions by the book "Build APIs you won't hate"

I used the `http_response_code()` method as suggested and set the code like this:

```
public function respondCreated($message) {
    $this->setStatusCode(201)->respond([
        'message' => $message
    ]);
    http_response_code(201);
    return $this;
}
```

When I then return the response code it shows properly, but the POSTMAN Status is still 200?

The helper method by laravel is `response()` and is described as:

```
Returning a full Response instance allows you to customize the response's HTTP status code and headers. A Response instance inherits from the Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response class, providing a variety of methods for building HTTP responses:

use Illuminate\Http\Response;

Route::get('home', function () {
    return (new Response($content, $status))
                  ->header('Content-Type', $value);
});
For convenience, you may also use the response helper:

Route::get('home', function () {
    return response($content, $status)
                  ->header('Content-Type', $value);
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: And where is the code which will set the actual HTTP status code header?

Comment: hm... well... how do I need to set this?

Comment: I don't know. What is all that `response()` and `->json()` and whatnot doing...!?

Comment: I have issues understanding how the "respondCreated" method would properly deliver it's return value to the client. I use the respond method but I guess I am missing something.

Comment: I looks you are using a framework and you don't know about its internals. Could you at least edit the question and say what framework it is?

Comment: I am using the Laravel framework and implemented the functions by the book "Build APIs you won't hate"

Comment: Why don't you just `return response()->json($yourArray, 201);`?

Comment: Actually I do this in my function: `public function respond($data, $headers = []) {
        return response()->json($data, $this->getStatusCode(), $headers);
    }`

But the POSTMAN output shows still 200 as response code

Answer (score -2):

You can set the HTTP Response Code as stated on [PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.http-response-code.php).

```
<?php

// Get the current default response code
var_dump(http_response_code()); // int(200)

// Set our response code
http_response_code(404);

// Get our new response code
var_dump(http_response_code()); // int(404)
?>
```

Comment: Post an example of how he could do it rather then just posting a link

Comment: The method is easy to use, does not have overloads and also I don't have the complete class of the asker to provide a complete example. I don't see any sense to provide a roman for a single method here.

Comment: If PHP changes its documentation site, your answer won't be useful anymore. The OP had an effort adding snippets of their code, let's do the same adding some insight for them and for any future reader. Also, as seen on OP code, he's actually using this method in their code.